# SQL Join which includes all elements of one table even if though don't match the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

Hi I'm knew to SQL but I was working my way through joins when I came across a this specific problem that i can't find a solution online.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have two tables which I need to join.

A Job table

A Job_Matches Table.

There is a list of ten jobs in the jobs table and in the the job_matches table there is a list of 60 or so people who have been matched to these jobs.So I want to make a list of the jobs in one column and the number of people matched to it in the other.
I used the following query

```
Select
Jobs.Id , count(Job_Matches.Job_id)
From
Jobs, Job_Matches
where
Jobs.Id = Job_Matches.job_id
group by (Jobs.id);
```

The tables match on Jobs.ID and Job_Matches.Job_Id

It did what I wanted except It leaves out any jobs that have zero people matched to it.So i got a list of 7 jobs back with the number of matches for each job in the second column.

It makes sense since its only matching where id's are equal and if there is no one matched to the job the id doesn't appear in the second table.

So I was wondering is there a way of saying this in the query:

if(Jobs.ID not in Job_Matches default zero) or something along those lines.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Oracle

```
SELECT
   Jobs.Id , count(Job_Matches.Job_id)
FROM
   Jobs, Job_Matches
WHERE
   Jobs.Id = Job_Matches.job_id(+)
GROUP BY Jobs.id;
```

But I recommend you to use the [ANSI syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join)

```
SELECT
   Jobs.Id , count(Job_Matches.Job_id)
FROM
   Jobs LEFT OUTER JOIN Job_Matches ON ( Jobs.Id = Job_Matches.job_id )
GROUP BY Jobs.id;
```

The Oracle syntax is old and it mixes the join with the `WHERE` clause.
It can be hard to see how the tables are joined with a complex query using this syntax

The ANSI syntax separates clearly the `WHERE` clause from the join. Oracle 10G supports the ANSI syntax. I don't know about previous versions.

Comment: Thanks This worked perfectly.
Ok so you think I should not bother with learning the Oracle Syntax and go with this ANSI?

Comment: @user183200 Don't use the `(+)` operator any longer. Oracle recommends to use ANSI JOINs instead. And as you are using SQL Server, you wouldn't be able to use that anyway.

Comment: Actually, they're *both* ANSI syntax, the old syntax is from SQL-89 (and earlier), whereas the new syntax became standard with SQL-92. Given we've had 20 years to adjust, it does seem time to stop using the old syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Jobs.Id , count(Job_Matches.Job_id)
From 
Jobs LEFT JOIN Job_Matches on
Jobs.Id = Job_Matches.job_id
group by (Jobs.id);
```

Comment: Cheers this did the job too but apparently I'm learning outdated syntax so better start again. Thanks again.